# Does it make sense to examine the dual of a feasbility problem?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, linear-programming

Consider a standard feasibility problem. The goal is to examine the state of feasible solutions for $Ax=b$ to find an $x$ that satisfies some property. Does the dual of this problem tell us anything about the solution? Since there is no objective function that we're examining I think the dual looks like $A^Tx \leq 0$. Is this right?

Comment: An equality can be replaced by an inequality and a suitable objective function to form a primal. Currently you took a zero function for your primal, which does not work.

Comment: The dual solution tells you something about the primal solution through complementary slackness.